# Tengo un problema con Python 3.7 y Sublime al usar "input"

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows10, sublimetext3

1) Ingrese el siguiente codigo en Sublime Text 3

```
print(5)
edad = int(input("Ingrese su edad: "))
print(edad)
```

2) Por consola me aparece lo siguiente:

```
5
Ingrese su edad:
```

E independientemente del numero que ingrese, el programa no hace nada mas, se queda en blanco. Al ejercutarlo en IDLE de Python sin embargo el programa se ejecuta perfectamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe cual podria ser el problema con el Sublime Text?

Comment: Al ejecutarlo comando por comando en IDLE el programa funciono perfectamente. El problema es al usar Sublime text 3, alguien sabra como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: por favor **[edit] la pregunta** y agrega una descripción clara de qué problemas tienes con este código.

Comment: Creo que la solución esta en este video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5-niid0m8A

Answer (score 0):

La razón es porque Sublime por defecto no soporta lo que quieres hacer.

Aunque no lo he usado, podrías intentar instalado este paquete [SublimeREPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) para que tengas esa funcionalidad.

De igual forma, puedes hacer tus pruebas directamente desde la terminal buscando el archivo y ejecutándolo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer para lograr interactuar con los inputs de Python es crear un nuevo build y que automáticamente te habrá una consola donde corra el programa.

1. Abre SublimeText y presiona en la opción **Tools** luego en la opción **Buil System**  presiona y se te abrirá una lista de lenguajes soportados y presiona en la última opción  **New Build System**
2. Se abrirá un documento en Sublime con la configuración genérica de un shell.
3. Sustituye todo por el siguiente texto. Dónde la parte de "C:/Python/python.exe" debes sustituirla por la ruta dónde está almacenado el programa de Python en tu ordenador.

   ```
   { "cmd: ["start", "cmd", "/k", "C:/Python/python.exe", "$file"],
     "Selector": "source.python",
     "Shell": true,
     "working_dir": "$file_dir"}
   ```
4. Presiona las teclas "Ctrl + s" y asignale un nombre  una vez guardado regresa a donde estan los Build System y selecciona el nombre que le diste a tu nueva configuración.

De ahora en adelante al presionar "Ctrl + b" se abrirá el archivo en una consola y será más rápido y fácil interactuar con el programa.

Answer (score 0):

COMO LOGRÉ QUE SUBLIME TEXT 3  ACEPTARA POR DEFECTO PYTHON3

Normalmente cuando se carga el sublime text 3, viene incluido el python 2.7 por defecto, y se hace imposible obligar a sublime text que tome por defecto el python 3. Perdiendo así muchas características nuevas que aporta el python3 en  beneficio del proceso e interpretación de los parámetros.

Pues bien lo primero que hice fue buscar con la instrucción “`which`” en una ventana del terminal, saber donde se encontraba el directorio del python donde lo tenía alojado sublime. Es decir:

Abre un terminal

```
$ which python3
```

En el caso de linux te va a responder que está en:

> /usr/bin

Múdate a este directorio y en el mismo vas a hacer lo siguiente:

`$ sudo cp python pythonr`  (Esto es sólo como precaución y tengas que volver atrás).

`$ sudo cp python3 python` (Copias la versión de python3 sobre el python ejecutable por sublime. Esto es para que sublime tome por defecto el python3.)

Esto es todo puedes probar llamando la consola del sublime y verás que te dice que
el python por defecto está en python3.

Sublime--->>Tools-->>Sublime REPL-->>python-->>python

Si por alguna razón no te da acceso a operaciones con estos archivos, nada mas debes cambiar la autorización de los mismos de esta manera:

```
$ sudo chmod 777 pytho*
```

Esto obliga a que los accesos de todo aquello que comienza por “pytho” sea autorizado para un uso general.

Comment: Con eso estarás machacando el python2, en caso de que lo necesites para otra cosa no lo tendrás disponible, no?

Comment: Para que vas a utilizar el python2. En todo caso puedes regresarlo como python version 2, sólo copiando de nuevo pythonr (el que protegiste, por si acaso) como phyton.  $ cp pythonr python.

Comment: Pues puedes querer utilizarlo porque tengas cualquier proyecto en tu pc que esté hecho para python2. Tiene que haber una manera de mantener ambas versiones instaladas y funcionando, e indicarle a Sublime cual escoger